# pd.to_datetime() is giving ValueError even when the value is correct

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am calling the following function

```
df = pd.to_datetime(col_data, infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
```

where `col_data` is a list of timestamp values of the format `'2023-04-24 17:33:23'` or `'2023-03-31 20:25:10.926000'`. It is working fine when I run it in a `test.py` file with hardcoded inputs, but when I run it with some data from a column in an Oracle SQL database it gives the following error which doesn't make sense:

> ValueError: time data "2023-04-24 17:33:23" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", at position 218. You might want to try:
> - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
> - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
> - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

I thought there could be something wrong with the data in the database but the value in the error statement shows that the input value is correct: Why is the value `"2023-04-24 17:33:23"` not matching the format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"`?

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your question (formatted as code)?

Comment: "*ValueError: time data "2023-04-24 17:33:23" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"*" -> you indeed don't have a `.%f` in your date format... Just try with the default `to_datetime` parameters.

Comment: In your hardcoded `test.py` file, does `'2023-04-24 17:33:23'` come before `'2023-03-31 20:25:10.926000'`? What happens if you switch the order?